# Send Screenshot of ViewController to other ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, uiviewcontroller

I would like to take a screenshot of **ViewController**, blur the image, send it to **ProfileViewController**, then set it as the background of **ProfileViewController**. This should not be that difficult as each task is pretty straightforward, I am just having difficulty finding the correct syntax as to how to do this.

The way I want this to work is such:

1. The user starts on **ViewController**, the main view.
2. Upon the click of a button (labeled *profTap*) the user is taken to **ProfileViewController**.
3. **ProfileViewController** is displayed through a segue (present modally) with its background set as a blurred image of the previous view from **ViewController**.

If someone could show me with code how to send the image to **ProfileViewController** I would be most appreciative. For reference, here is my code below that I have for now of the **ViewController**. I believe I am capturing the image correctly, I am jsut not sure what to do from here to send it to the **ProfileViewController.**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "ProfileViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)profTap:(id)sender {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainView.bounds.size);
    [self.mainView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *mainViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(mainViewImage);

    // NEXT: blur image, and send to ProfileViewControoler

//    UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mainViewImage"]];
//    [self.view addSubview:backgroundView];

}


- (IBAction)unwindToHome:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {

}


@end
```

Comment: You are asking two separate questions. How to blur and how to send the final image to the new controller. Please only ask one question per post.

Comment: well I am actually asking four questions: how to screen shot, blur, send, and set as background. I guess my real question is how to send the "blurred image" to the other controller. I guess i will edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that

```
   @interface ViewController ()
    @property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *backgroundImage;
    @end
    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)profTap:(id)sender {

}


- (IBAction)unwindToHome:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
     self.backgroundImage = [self takeSnapShot];
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nameofyoursegue" sender:nil];
}
//function to take a screenshot of your current controller
- (UIImage *)takeSnapShot {
  // Create the image context
    CGRect bounds = self.mainView.bounds;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, NO,
                                           self.view.window.screen.scale);
    [self.navigationController.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:bounds
                                         afterScreenUpdates:NO];

  // Get the snapshot
  UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  // Be nice and clean your mess up
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return snapshotImage;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"nameofyoursegue"]) {

    ProfileViewController *profileViewController =
        [segue destinationViewController];
    [profileViewController setBackgroundImage:self.backgroundImage];
  }

}


@end
```

PhotoViewController

```
@interface ProfileViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImageView;
            @property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *backgroundImage;
            @end
@implementation ProfileViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
 [self.backgroundImageView
        setImage:self.backgroundImage];
}
@end
```

About the blur effect, I advice you to use FXBlurView in your ProfileViewController  :
https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView

Comment: Thanks! this helped quite a bit