# Screenshot of previous UIViewController after orientation changed

Tags: ios, swift

I implemented exactly what described in this post:
[Send Screenshot of ViewController to other ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925446/send-screenshot-of-viewcontroller-to-other-viewcontroller)

But I have an issue after orientation is changed in 'ProfileViewController'. I tried to get a screenshot of 'ViewController' but I just get the image of the view in previous orientation.

I tried things like this, but nothing appears to help:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil, completion: { (context : UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext!) -> Void in
        var viewController = self.navigationController!.viewControllers[0] as! UIViewController

        viewController.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        viewController.view.setNeedsLayout()
        viewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.backgroundImage = viewController.getImageDump()
    })

    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
}
```

'getImageDump' is an extension method on UIViewController:

```
func getImageDump() -> UIImage {
    var size = view.bounds.size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0);
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image
}
```

**EDIT:** Already fixed it; just set size of the viewcontroller manually. So instead of

```
        viewController.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        viewController.view.setNeedsLayout()
        viewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

just do

```
        viewController.view.frame.size = size
```

Answer (score 0):

Use snapshot instead

```
- (UIView *)snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.
After calling this method 'view.size' is still the old value and I got an black image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Change

```
    var size = view.bounds.size
```

To

```
var size = view.frame.size
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Just like view.bounds.size, view.frame.size value is always {1024, 748} (when initial orientation was landscape...).